# What's the more appropriate way to introduce a "flashback" in a graphic novel, in terms of color, line strokes and panel shape?

Tags: color, stroke, comics

i'm in the process of making a graphic novel together with a scriptwriter. We're both at our first attempt in making a graphic novel although we are not new in drawing (me) and scripting (him).

This is the first time that i have to deal with a *"flashback"* situation without explicitly stating FLASHBACK (or whatever kind of sentence may work) on the panel. Just drawings, no captions or baloons.

I thought of a change of the mood (light color) and play with the resemblance of the charachter in the past, but i don't know if it's enough.

There is also the possibility (i've not read the whole script yet) that i would have to draw flashbacks occurring into another flashback, someone would say *"flashbackception"*?

How should i handle this?

Any advice, experience or useful links on the topic are appreciated.

**EDIT: What i've read so far**

- http://www.comicon.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=217624
- http://www.bigredhair.com/work/comics.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZ4FY-f_Y5c
- http://selfpubauthors.com/2013/10/13/how-to-do-a-flashback/

Comment: Other saying 'they should look different' there's no specific rule here. Google will provide you with plenty of options to consider. One of many google results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZ4FY-f_Y5c

Comment: Really interesting question, though a tad broad. As with all things this depends on context. I've seen this done in many different ways depending on the rest of the style. I think this might work better if you use our Critique Guidelines and post a flashback page and regular page to get a better answer... Here's the guidelines: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work

Comment: @DA01 i've seen almost everything google could offer me, i'll edit my question with what i've read so far.

Comment: @Ryan i'm still far from the first sketch (we are in the charachters definition phase) so i have nothing to show at the moment. I'll edit the question when i have something, thanks.

Comment: The most obvious thing to do would be to very obviously change the saturation of flashback panels (maybe even go full black + white?). I've also seen a slight blur vignette around the edges of flashback panels in webcomics quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Using black as the outer colour of the panels seems to work in my experience.

Here's an example:
http://www.hoodedutilitarian.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/scottpilgrim4.jpg

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

I'm only making a brainstorm here:

**You can play with the style of the background perhaphs:**

- Lot less detail
- In negative if it is black and white
- Diferent color schemes, the sky not blue for example
- All the flashbacks in a dawn, or with a dramathic ilumination in interiors.
- Blurry ones
- Curvier or straighter lines

**Start with a close up of the main character on that flashback, the eyes?**

**Diferent camera angle**

Answer (score 0):

try splitting the illustration into half diagonally with 'two lines ~'like a thin thunder bolt'... and now fade/feather/blur one section of the illustration for the effect.
hope this helps